# How to set Brush from RGB or hex

Tags: c#, .net, wpf-brushes

Hey I want to set color of BorderBrush in .xaml.cs file and don't want to use colours like Red or Green and want to use whole palette from HEX or RGB. I don't know how to covert it. Maybe you know how to solve this problem.

```
    private void TxbName_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        txbName.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
        txblImie.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ConvertFrom` method from `BrushConverter`.

```
var converter=new BrushConverter();
txblImie.Foreground = (Brush)converter.ConvertFrom("#ff0000");
```

Comment: Error CS1002 ; expected 
Error CS1526 A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type
Error CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Brush' 
Error CS0149 Method name expected        It's not working:(